# CSS div stacking strategy, scrolling + pinned areas

Tags: html, css

I want to make a time schedule for a school in html.
It should look like the mockup below.

[mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWpCp.png)

I have tried several things but I was never able to achieve all of the following things at once.

- if there are too many teachers or days the blue box should be scrollable
- the teachers on the left and the header should be fixed (like pinned in excel)
- when scrolling horizontally in the blue area the so pinned header or teachers should follow
- The activities can be placed in the blue area without the use of a grid (they are irregular) and expand the blue div if necessary.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to approach this?